# How to prevent my mail from being used in PHP?

Tags: email, security

I have a custom email address with my web domain, and the issue is that I found that anybody could impersonate me, using my personal address, with a very basic PHP script using `mail`.

Is there any way to prevent anybody to use my email address with such scripts ?

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP? People can spoof your address using any language, even simple shell scripts.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for this information, I was not aware of that. I will take a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to protect a *server* so that it cannot be used for email spoofing.

However, since there will always be unsecured servers, spoofing cannot be prevented. In particular, there is nothing an *email address owner* can do to ensure their email address will not be spoofed.

The only effective countermeasure would be to sign all your email and to warn any correspondents that unsigned email is not from you; but there are significant problems with this approach that make it a non-viable solution: not all email clients support signing; there are different competing protocols; receivers don't typically verify messages; it is harder to notice that something is absent than that something is present; the majority of users are not even aware of the concept of email signing...

In the end, the only remaining option is for all receivers to be vigilant, and inspect the email headers for discrepancies.